# Calculate rank of binary matrix with larger size

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

Hell all, I have some problem when compute the rank of binary matrix that only 1 or 0. The rank of binary matrix will based on the row reduction using boolean operations XOR. Let see the XOR operation:

```
1 xor 1 =0
1 xor 0= 1 
0 xor 0= 0
0 xor 1= 1
```

Given a binary matrix as

```
A =

     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0     0     1
```

We can see the third row equals first row xor with second row. Hence, the rank of matrix A only 2, instead of 3 by rank matlab function.
I have one way to compute the extractly rank of binary matrix using this code

```
B=gf(A)
rank(B)
```

It will return 2. However, when I compute with large size of matrix, for example 400 by 400. It does not return the rank (never stop). Could you suggest to me the good way to find rank of binary matrix for large size? Thank all 
UPDATE: this is computation time using tic toc

```
N=50; Elapsed time is=0.646823 seconds
N=100;Elapsed time is 3.123573 seconds.
N=150;Elapsed time is 7.438541 seconds.
N=200;Elapsed time is 11.349964 seconds.
N=400;Elapsed time is 66.815286 seconds.
```

Note that check rank is only the condition in my algorithm. However, it take very long long time, then it will affect to my method
Base on the suggestion of R. I will use Gaussian Elimination to find the rank. This is my code. However, it call the rank function (spend some computation times). Could you modify help me without using rank function?

```
function rankA=GaussEliRank(A)  
    mat = A;
    [m n] = size(A);              % read the size of the original matrix A
    for i = 1 : n
        j = find(mat(i:m, i), 1); % finds the FIRST 1 in i-th column starting at i
        if isempty(j)
                mat = mat( sum(mat,2)>0 ,:);
                rankA=rank(mat);  %%Here
                return;
        else
            j = j + i - 1;       % we need to add i-1 since j starts at i
            temp = mat(j, :); % swap rows
            mat(j, :) = mat(i, :);
            mat(i, :) = temp;
            % add i-th row to all rows that contain 1 in i-th column
            % starting at j+1 - remember up to j are zeros
            for k = find(mat( (j+1):m, i ))' 
                mat(j + k, :) = bitxor(mat(j + k, :), mat(i, :));
            end
        end
    end
    %remove all-zero rows if there are some
    mat = mat( sum(mat,2)>0 ,:);
    if any(sum( mat(:,1:n) ,2)==0) % no solution because matrix A contains
        error('No solution.');  % all-zero row, but with nonzero RHS
    end
    rankA=rank(mat); %%Here

end
```

Let check the matrix A at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/glt4y90mfr6tq06/A.mat?dl=0). Correct ans is 393 for rank of A.

Comment: I am surprised this isn't working already.  Your method seems to be perfectly fine.  If you try with N=50,100,200,300,etc. how long does the computation take in Matlab?  If you really need to do it yourself then a simple O(n^3) method is to use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz: I update my question that has some information that you need. My goal only reduce the computation time for check rank of binary matrix. As you know Gaussian elimination is only resolved if the matrix A is full rank. That is reason why I must check rank first.

Comment: Gaussian elimination can also be used to compute the rank: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_ranks_and_bases

Comment: I am using Gaussian Elimination to find solution of Ax=b. However, Matrix A is created randomly, so sometime it will return the solution, sometime returns more than one solution. That is why I check the rank of matrix first. Gaussian Elimination can use for my binary matrix? Do you have any reference matlab code

Comment: Are you only interested in calculating the rank or getting the reduced A too?

Comment: I only want to compute rank of binary matrix A as fast as possible. I don't care the output of A.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz and Divakar: Please check my solution. It take small time than rank of gf matrix. However, it use rank function before return. Let see and modify help me without using rank function.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the matrix into row echelon form with Gaussian elimination, the rank is the number of nonzero rows. You should be able to replace the code after the loop with something like `rankA=sum(sum(mat,2)>0);`.

Comment: How about the if isempty(j)....I tried to replace by your code, but it is not correct compare with rank function. You can download matrix A at https://www.dropbox.com/s/glt4y90mfr6tq06/A.mat?dl=0

Comment: @user3051460 Do nothing and move on to the next column. "It doesn't work" is not helpful for debugging, so could you post a small example and how the outputs differ?

Comment: Let check the my code and my example of A. If you use rank(A), it will return 400. However, if you use my function, the rank is 393 that similar with rank of binary matrix as I explained

Comment: Elsenstat: Do you check my solution. Please try to run it and let me know the improvement without using rank function before return to get true result